# NSOpenPanel and detected leaked observer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I received a warning from XCode during the execution of my program :

```
2016-01-21 03:19:26.468 IsoMetadonnees[1975:303] An instance 0x1004eefd0 of class NSVBOpenPanel was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
  <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x608000444710> (
  <NSKeyValueObservance 0x6080000d5310: Observer: 0x100592cf0, Key path: level, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x6080004486a0>
  )
```

The problem occurs while the application presents an NSOpenPanel to select some files that will be asynchronously loaded. The application does not crash and file are correctly loaded...

I don't create any value observer, so I imagine that the observer is created by NSOpenPanel, but I don't know any procedure to remove observer that I have not created...

Despite of this warning, I have made multiple loads without notice any crash. I use my application since many years without any problems, but I recently switch to ARC; may be the problem appeared (or is detected) at this time.

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```
- (IBAction)ajoutFichier:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel  *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    // Here some configurations of openPanel

    if ([openPanel runModal] == NSOKButton) {
        tmp_listeURLFichiers = [openPanel URLs];
    }
    //[openPanel close]; // I add this code unsuccessfully
    openPanel = nil; // I add this code unsuccessfully

    // I call a task in back ground to load my files
    if ((tmp_listeURLFichiers != nil) && ([tmp_listeURLFichiers count]>0))
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(ajouteListeFichiers:) withObject:tmp_listeURLFichiers];
}

// Load files in background
-(BOOL) ajouteListeFichiers:(NSArray *)listeDesFichierAAjouter {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Some stuff to show a progress bar

        // Loop to load selected files
        for (id tmpCheminVersMonImage in listeDesFichierAAjouter) {
            // Load files
        }


    }   //  <========== THE WARNING OCCURS AT THIS POINT, WHEN autoreleasepool is cleaned
    return (YES);
}
```

I try adding

```
[openPanel close];
```

and

```
openPanel = nil;
```

to force releasing openPanel from memory (and thus observers) before starting background task, but that doesn't change anything...

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What is `NSVBOpenPanel`? Do you add any observers? Did you set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak and po the observer?

Comment: I don't know what NSVBOpenPanel is... I only use NSOpenPanel. I guess NSVBOpenPanel is a kind of NSOpenPanel when we use sandbox.
I set a breakpoint the way the warning tell me to do and I could determin that the warning was occured at the drain ot the autorelease pool (the point I indicate on the code) in my first post.
And I did not add any observer...

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem using the following trick :

I declare a variable in my view controller :

```
__strong NSOpenPanel  *prgOpenPanel;
```

Then I use it in my code

```
//NSOpenPanel  *prgOpenPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
self.prgOpenPanel = nil;
self.prgOpenPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
// Here some configurations of openPanel

if ([prgOpenPanel runModal] == NSOKButton) {
    tmp_listeURLFichiers = [prgOpenPanel URLs];
    if ((tmp_listeURLFichiers != nil) && ([tmp_listeURLFichiers count]>0))
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(ajouteListeFichiers:) withObject:tmp_listeURLFichiers];
}
```

No more warnings !